# Problem with a array overwriting another in a structure in C

Tags: arrays, c, struct

Ok guys, I have a problem.
I'm quite a beginner in C and I have to code a Sokoban game in C (in terminal).
I use some structures to store my variables and scene, here they are (there are another one but it's just a vector2)  :

```
struct carte //couldn't use map cause of c++
{
    char ** carte;
    int line;
    int column;
};
typedef struct carte carte;

struct gameObject
{
    char sprite;
    vect2 * pos;
};
typedef struct gameObject gameObject;

struct interupteur
{
    gameObject gO;
    int active; //bool
};
typedef struct interupteur interupteur;

struct scene
{
    carte * carte;
    gameObject * chara;
    //array containing all the boxes
    gameObject * box;
    //array containing the switches
    interupteur * inter;
    int nbInter;
    int nbBox;
};
typedef struct scene scene;
```

I use a function to serialize my scene from a txt file. It works except for one thing : the inter (switch) array and the box array have the same content meaning the switch from my map (see below) override the box. So from the following txt I get to this :

```
in the txt     results
######         ######
#    #         #    #
#P  C#         #P   #
#    #         #    #
#   I#         #   I#
######         ######
```

So here is how I allocated my scene and my two arrays (let's forget the error case of NULL pointers) :

```
scene * scene1 = malloc(sizeof(scene));
scene1->box = malloc(scene1->nbBox*sizeof(gameObject));
scene1->inter = malloc(scene1->nbInter*sizeof(interupteur));
```

So I store the content of the txt in a 2d array of char and replace the P (player), C (box) and I (switch) with a space and store them elsewhere in my scene struct.

```
    for(int i = 0 ; i < scene1->carte->ligne ; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < scene1->carte->colonne ; j++)
        {
            fscanf(f,"%c",&(scene1->carte->carte[i][j]));
            if(scene1->carte->carte[i][j] == 'P')
            {
                scene1->carte->carte[i][j] = ' ';
                scene1->chara->pos->x = i;
                scene1->chara->pos->y = j;
                scene1->chara->sprite = 'P';
            }
            else if(scene1->carte->carte[i][j] == 'I')
            {
                scene1->carte->carte[i][j] = ' ';
                scene1->inter[k2].gO.pos->x = i;
                scene1->inter[k2].gO.pos->y = j;
                scene1->inter[k2].gO.sprite = 'I';
                k1++;
            }
            else if(scene1->carte->carte[i][j] == 'C')
            {
                scene1->carte->carte[i][j] = ' ';
                scene1->box[k1].pos->x = i;
                scene1->box[k1].pos->y = j;
                scene1->box[k1].sprite = 'C';
                k1++;
            }
```

I checked and it doesn't come from my output function. It come from my serialization function, the box is here until the function read the switch and override it. I also checked the address of the two arrays and they're different.
At first I was thinking it was a padding issue but I don't use union so I really don't know. I searched on internet and didn't find anything. Can somebody explain me why I have this problem ?
I code on Windows 10 using code blocks.

PS : Excuse me if my post isn't clear it is my first one and please excuse my English it isn't my native language.

I tried to change the order of the if/else if but it didn't change the overwriting (but create quite a mess). Expect that I didn't tried much more because I really don't see where the issue come from.

Edit : Here is my full code, you can use it as a minimal exemple (I don't know if it is minimal enough) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct vect2
{
    int x;
    int y ;
};
typedef struct vect2 vect2;

struct carte //couldn't use map cause of c++
{
    char ** carte;
    int line;
    int column;
};
typedef struct carte carte;

struct gameObject
{
    char sprite;
    vect2 * pos;
};
typedef struct gameObject gameObject;

struct interupteur
{
    gameObject gO;
    int active; //bool
};
typedef struct interupteur interupteur;

struct scene
{
    carte * carte;
    gameObject * chara;
    //array containing all the boxes
    gameObject * box;
    //array containing the switches
    interupteur * inter;
    int nbInter;
    int nbBox;
};
typedef struct scene scene;

scene * Update(scene * scene1)
{
    int k1 = 0, k2 = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i< scene1->carte->line;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < scene1->carte->column ; j++)
        {
            if(scene1->inter[k2].gO.pos->x == i && scene1->inter[k2].gO.pos->y == j)
            {
                printf("%c",scene1->inter[k1].gO.sprite);
                k2++;
            }
            else if(scene1->chara->pos->x == i && scene1->chara->pos->y == j)
            {
                printf("%c",scene1->chara->sprite);
            }
            else if(scene1->box[k1].pos->x == i && scene1->box[k1].pos->y == j)
            {
                printf("%c",scene1->box[k1].sprite);
                k1++;
            }
            else
                printf("%c",scene1->carte->carte[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return scene1;
}

scene * SerialMap(const char * path)
{
    scene * scene1 = malloc(sizeof(scene));
    scene1->carte = malloc(sizeof(carte));
    FILE * f =  fopen(path,"r+");

    //Look for dimension of the map, assuming the lines have the same lentgh, count box and switch
    scene1->carte->column = 0;
    scene1->carte->line = 0;
    char c;
    int k = 0;
    scene1->nbInter = 0;
    scene1->nbBox = 0;
    for(c = fgetc(f); c != EOF ; c = fgetc(f))
    {
        if(c == '\n')
        {
            scene1->carte->column = k;
            scene1->carte->line++;
            k = 0;
        }
        if(c == 'C')
            scene1->nbBox++;
        if(c == 'I')
            scene1->nbInter++;
        k++;
    }
    rewind(f);


    //Alloc map array
    scene1->carte->carte = malloc(scene1->carte->line * sizeof(char *));
    for(int i = 0 ; i < scene1->carte->line ; i++)
        scene1->carte->carte[i] = malloc(scene1->carte->column * sizeof(char));

    //Alloc switch and box array
    scene1->box = malloc(scene1->nbBox*sizeof(gameObject));
    scene1->inter = malloc(scene1->nbInter*sizeof(interupteur));
    scene1->chara = malloc(sizeof(gameObject));
    scene1->chara->pos = malloc(sizeof(vect2));


    //Serial map in 2d array and store box, switch and player
    int k1 = 0, k2 = 0; //k1 is used for the box tab and k2 for the swith tab
    for(int i = 0 ; i < scene1->carte->line ; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < scene1->carte->column ; j++)
        {
            fscanf(f,"%c",&(scene1->carte->carte[i][j]));
            if(scene1->carte->carte[i][j] == 'P')
            {
                scene1->carte->carte[i][j] = ' ';
                scene1->chara->pos->x = i;
                scene1->chara->pos->y = j;
                scene1->chara->sprite = 'P';
            }
            else if(scene1->carte->carte[i][j] == 'I')
            {
                scene1->carte->carte[i][j] = ' ';
                scene1->inter[k2].gO.pos->x = i;
                scene1->inter[k2].gO.pos->y = j;
                scene1->inter[k2].gO.sprite = 'I';
                k2++;
            }
            else if(scene1->carte->carte[i][j] == 'C')
            {
                scene1->carte->carte[i][j] = ' ';
                scene1->box[k1].pos->x = i;
                scene1->box[k1].pos->y = j;
                scene1->box[k1].sprite = 'C';
                k1++;
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(f);
    return scene1;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    scene * gamescene = SerialMap(argv[1]);
    gamescene  = Update(gamescene);
    return 0;
}
```

You can use the example I gave in the second code block.

Comment: The `'I'` branch is incrementing `k1` instead of `k2`. That's definitely wrong, but we don't have enough info to tell if that's the bug you're asking about, or a different bug. A [mcve] would enable us to do more.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks, I corrected the wrong incrementation but it changed nothing to the issue
I edited the post to add my full code.